# Finite critical points of a polynomial are preperiodic implies the Fatou set is connected and simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, dynamical-systems, rational-functions, complex-dynamics

I'm currently going through Alan Beardon's book "Iteration of Rational Functions" and I'm a little stuck on his explanation of Corollary 9.5.3. which states that "If every finite critical points of a polynomial is preperiodic, then the Fatou set is connected and simply connected".

I understand that if the Fatou set is not connected, then there must exist a periodic Fatou component that contains a finite critical point and isn't $F_\infty$. However apparently, the assumption that all critical points are preperiodic gives us a contradiction here.. but I'm not sure how.

If anyone could break down his argument, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Beardon's argument]

Comment: Congratulations, your post is the $1,600,000^{\text{th}}$ question in this website.